# Making a Repeating Sequence of Characters Count Method Faster

Tags: java

i'm currently working on a moderation system for a Twitch chat bot, I made this method to find the longest sequence of a repeating character, thing is I don't know which character or where it will be repeated since this method will be used to check random messages. Can anyone help me simplify and make the code below more permanent?

```
public int getLongestLetterSequence(String message) {
    int biggestRepeatingCount = 0;
    int totalRepeatingCharacters = 0;
    char currentRepeatingCharacter = message.charAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        char c = message.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            if (c == currentRepeatingCharacter) {
                biggestRepeatingCount++;
            } else {
                if (totalRepeatingCharacters < biggestRepeatingCount) {
                    totalRepeatingCharacters = biggestRepeatingCount;
                }
                biggestRepeatingCount = 0;
            }
        }
        currentRepeatingCharacter = c;
    }

    return totalRepeatingCharacters + 1;
}
```

Comment: You should look into regular expressions.

Comment: This considers the `charAt(0)` twice making it look like a repeating character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is regex based solution, which is much more concise than your current approach.  It attempts to find repeating sequences using the pattern:

```
(.)(\\1)+
```

This says to match, and capture, any single character, which is then followed by that same character one or more times.  We keep track on the longest running repeating sequence, and then display it at the end.

```
String input = "The quick brown bbb fox jumps over the aaaaaa lazy dog zzz.";

String longest = "";
String pattern = "(.)(\\1)+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(0).length() > longest.length()) {
        longest = m.group(0);
    }
}

System.out.println("Longest sequence: " + longest);

Longest sequence: aaaaaa
```

The advantage of this regex solution is that it is perhaps easier to read than your current approach.  But, a solution using only base string functions may actually run faster than this.

Comment: I had something like this in mind as well before starting, however like you said, regex might be slower in general.

Comment: @scaniatv you should prefer readability over performance unless you have a reason not to.. do you?

Comment: @scaniatv You can benchmark both approaches and get some idea.  If they are close to each other in performance, then choose the approach which you find easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I suspect the OP is planning to use this in some real time system which will processing tons of data coming from Twitter.  So, this might actually be a case where performance is an issue.

Comment: Yeah i'll test the performance and choose from there, if it's not a big difference, I'll go with your way. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with something to improve the performance (and also found an error in your code).

### An error

You have the following code:

```
if (c == currentRepeatingCharacter) {
    biggestRepeatingCount++;
} else {
    if (totalRepeatingCharacters < biggestRepeatingCount) {
        totalRepeatingCharacters = biggestRepeatingCount;
    }
    biggestRepeatingCount = 0;
}
```

However the `totalRepeatingCharacters` will *only* be set if it sees a character that's not equal to the `currentRepeatingCharacter`, and *this* becomes an issue:

```
    String string =
            "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasidhihasdbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
```

It finds length `24` for this `String` which is the same as the length of `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa".length() + 1`. Like stated before the number only updates after another character is found, and even though the amount of `b` characters is greater it's not followed by another character and therefore not registered.

**The fix**

Move the `if` statement to another position like so:

```
if (c == currentRepeatingCharacter) {
    biggestRepeatingCount++;
    if (totalRepeatingCharacters < biggestRepeatingCount) {
        totalRepeatingCharacters = biggestRepeatingCount;
    }
} else {
    biggestRepeatingCount = 0;
}
```

### Performance improvement

When you're traversing through the `String` you can eventually stop since the amount of characters left in the `String` is smaller than the `totalRepeatingCharacters` and therefore there's no way `totalRepeatingCharacters` will ever be increased (the max value has already been found)

```
if (c == currentRepeatingCharacter) {
    biggestRepeatingCount++;
    if (totalRepeatingCharacters < biggestRepeatingCount) {
        totalRepeatingCharacters = biggestRepeatingCount;
    }
} else {
    if(string.length() - i <= maxRepeatingCount + 1) {
        if (totalRepeatingCharacters < biggestRepeatingCount) {
            totalRepeatingCharacters = biggestRepeatingCount;
        }
        break;
    }
    biggestRepeatingCount = 0;
}
```

We only check if this is the case when we are switching to a new character. For some `String`s the code will have a shorter execution time now:

```
String string =
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasidhxhazdbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";
```

When it gets to character `h` it will `break` out of the `for` loop since there's no way `totalRepeatingCharacters` will ever be greater than it already is.